# Read write file in specific manner

Tags: java, android

I have read and write file in a specific manner.

Format of file:

```
a1(1,2,5,8,0);
a2(4,6,8,4);
a7(4,5,7,8);
```

At a time if I modify section for a2 say like `"2,4,6,8"`, how should I modify the file.

And how can I read values for specific title. That is, if I want to fetch values only for a7, then the method should return `4,5,7,8`.

Thank You

Comment: you should show some code that you've tried

Answer (score 2):

***"how should I modify the file"***

To modify the content of the file, you need to write it into the temporary file. After you finish, delete the original and rename the temporary file as the original file name.

***"how can I read values for specific title"***

Read the file line by line and search for your specific title:

```
if(line.contains("a7")){
   System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf("("),line.indexOf(")")+1));
}
```